# Where can I find the description about SSServerErrorDomain in Apple iAP?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We have a App, it collected some error code from Apple iAP purchase.
In the collect-dashboard, we see some error code report, but can not find the exact meanings.

Like: "SSServerErrorDomain - 2004", "SSServerErrorDomain - 2037", etc.

I find the Apple development website, and others. But I can not get the result.

Is there any one can explain or give me a link with description about the SSServerErrorDomain constant?