# Subscription downgrade in sandbox produces SSServerErrorDomain/SKErrorDomain (code 0) error

Tags: ios, storekit

I got this when downgrading a subscription. The `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` function provides a transaction with error `Error Domain=SSServerErrorDomain Code=0 "You are all set" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=You are all set}` and state as `.failed`.

Note the error domain is **SSServerErrorDomain**
NOT the more common SKErrorDomain. There seems to be [no documentation about SSServerErrorDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42266047/where-can-i-find-the-description-about-ssservererrordomain-in-apple-iap?s=2%7C1.7831) either.

If I try to purchase the same downgraded plan again, I will get “You are already subscribed.”.

The receipt right after the downgrade does not contain the new plan, which is expected because a downgrade will take effect at next renewal date. After 1 hour, I check the receipt again and it contains the new downgraded plan. (Monthly subscription interval is 5 mins in sandbox, and renews for about 6 times.)

I don't think we can do anything here because it comes from StoreKit. May be it's an Apple sandbox bug.

Steps to Reproduce:

- Set up 2 subscriptions with different levels (will call plan A and B) in a subscription group in iTunes Connect
- Go to the app, purchase the plan with higher level (A), observe successful purchase
- Then immediately purchase lower level plan (B)
- Got the mentioned error.

Version:
iOS 10.3.2 (14F89), iPhone 7 plus

Seems like some other people are seeing this also: https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit/issues/231

I filed a radar: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4998361958580224

Questions:

- Has anyone experience this?
- Could this be a sandbox only issue?
- If it's also in production, how can I get around this?

Update:
I tested again today and it's returning error domain `SKErrorDomain code=0` now. Apple, please tell us how to test subscription downgrade!

Comment: Hey Hlung, did you ever solve this issue? I'm seeing the exact same issue. It's confusing that we're getting an error with the success message.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with refreshing receipt just after paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: gets called? Are you receiving receipt with plan B?

Comment: If SKReceiptRefreshRequest API refresh is not showing plan B in latest receipt then it is Sandbox environment issue.

Comment: If you need immediate resolution , then raise  1 Technical support issue from developers account [Code Level Support -> Request Technical Support].

Comment: Plan B actually got added after first renewal date, which is expected for a downgrade. Thanks for the TSI request suggestion!